# having vuefire+firebase binding collections error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I'm building web app using VueFire and Firebase.

There are two collections in my Realtime Database:

```
cities:{
    0: {
        name: Berlin,
        countryId: 0
    },
    1: {
        name: Paris,
        countryId: 1
    },
    ...
},
countries:{
    0: {
        name: Germany,
    },
    1: {
        name: France,
    },
    ...
},
```

In Vue component I'm trying to get list of (city name + country name):

```
<div v-for="(city, indx) in cities" :key="indx">
    <div>{{city.name}}, {{countries[city.countryId].name}}</div>
</div>

export default {
    firebase: {
      cities: db.ref('cities'),
      countries: db.ref('countries'),
    }
}
```

having this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 
'countryId' of undefined"
```

if only {{city.name}} - ok.

What's wrong? How can I bind this 2 collections the right way to got what I want?

Comment: and this {{cities[0].countryId}} also cause the same error

Answer (score 0):

As firebase takes some time to fetch data, the DOM is getting loaded first.

you may try doing like this.

```
firebase: {
  citiesFromdb: db.ref('cities'),
  countriesFromdb: db.ref('countries'),
}
computed: {
    cities() {
        return this.citiesFromdb;
    },
    countries(){
      return this.countriesFromdb;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, to use computed (and different hooks as well), but unfortunately it didn't help to solve the problem

Comment: is it possible to do console.log(countries), or it gives error

Comment: console.log(this.countries) - (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer] - no error, with all true data inside the array and objects

Comment: This means your countries collection is an array and not the kind of data(object) that you are showing in your question?

Comment: оh, I made a mistake in database description. countries is an array.